# Estimating autocovariance from repeated time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, spectral-analysis, acf-pacf

Consider a parent process $Z_t$ whose characteristics I wish to estimate. Consider two time series (or any stochastic process) realizations of this parent process
$$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_T\,, $$
and
$$Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_T\,. $$

That is, $Cov(X_1, X_{1+s}) = Cov(Y_1, Y_{1+s})$ in addition to them having the same stationary distribution. Then I would think that in order to estimate the lag-$s$ autocovariance, I can first define an overall mean
$$\mu_{X,Y} = \dfrac{1}{2T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}X_t + \dfrac{1}{2T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} Y_t\,, $$
and measure deviation around $\mu_{X,Y}$. That is, for a parent process $Z_t$
$$ 
\widehat{\text{Cov}}(Z_1, Z_{1+s}) = \dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{j=1}^{n - s}(X_{1} - \mu_{X,Y})(X_{1 + j} - \mu_{X,Y}) + \dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{j=1}^{n - s}(Y_{1} - \mu_{X,Y})(Y_{1 + j} - \mu_{X,Y})\,.
$$

The alternative is that I average the individual lag-$s$ covariances
$$ 
\widehat{\text{Cov}}(Z_1, Z_{1+s}) = \dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{j=1}^{n - s}(X_{1} - \mu_{X})(X_{1 + j} - \mu_{X}) + \dfrac{1}{2T}\sum_{j=1}^{n - s}(Y_{1} - \mu_{Y})(Y_{1 + j} - \mu_{Y})\,.
$$

Are there any references to know what are the properties of these two estimators, and which is known to be better? I would guess that the first one is better since I am using a better estimate of the mean to measure the deviation around.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks, any insights?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. But I guess there should be some literature on modelling and estimation when multiple trajectories generated by the same process are available. Need to find it...

Comment: The estimators based on separate means will be more robust to deviations from stationarity (such as might occur when the observations are at different, non-overlapping times).  As such I would expect them to be more powerful and more useful in most applications.

Comment: @whuber Fair point. But what if I can safely assume stationarity?